# Webrtc does not generate TCP ICEs, only UDP on Android

Tags: android, webrtc, turn, rtcpeerconnection

We are implementing Webrtc in our app. Library version: `implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039'`. On Android it generates only UDP ICE candidates, on IOS both UDP and TCP, though lib versions are the latest on both and settings are about the same. We think because of that some calls that needs TURN are not working immediately, but only after reconnect, when webrtc library changes its state to Failed, and we resend an offer, which already contains ICEs. Here are my settings for Peerconnection:

```
  PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig =
            new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(peerIceServers);
    rtcConfig.tcpCandidatePolicy = PeerConnection.TcpCandidatePolicy.ENABLED;
    rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = PeerConnection.BundlePolicy.MAXBUNDLE;
    rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = PeerConnection.RtcpMuxPolicy.REQUIRE;
    rtcConfig.continualGatheringPolicy = PeerConnection.ContinualGatheringPolicy.GATHER_CONTINUALLY;
    // Use ECDSA encryption.
    rtcConfig.keyType = PeerConnection.KeyType.ECDSA;
```

What kind of settings should i setup in order to make Webrtc library generate TCP ICEs too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved by double-generating offer and sending the second one. It turned out the second offer already contains ICEs, still UDP-only, and no need to send them individually. I do not know why, but it helped.

Comment: could you please share some snippets of the code? How you achieved it? I'm developing android video calling app. It works fine on WiFi but when on mobile data appRtcClient.sendOfferSdp(desc); is called after a long time. Could you please help?

Comment: just generate and send offer again